# Magento-2-Paypal orders not showing in magento end?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-express, ipn

In Magento-2 when we place order through paypal payment method then payment successful at paypal end and all data related to transaction display perfect but when we look in magento admin the order data of those orders do not show.
It happens not for all paypal orders having for random orders.
Please suggest what we should do in this case.

> Main error : order ID is incorrect. Verify the ID and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): The "50012081" order ID is incorrect. Verify the ID and try again. at vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Ipn.php:146)"

what i have done so far :

Enabled Paypal debug mode on.
Checked all log SetExpressCheckout,getExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckout reponses are showing success acknowledgement.

Comment: Have you found solution for this issue?